# Crypt returns hash or digest?

Tags: c, cryptography, crypt

I am a little confused.When i call crypt with salt and passphrase the string that is returned is called hash or digest?I am confused because i know that what is returned from a cryptographic function is called hash.But when we call crypt we also pass salt as argument.
Can we say that:

```
digest=$id$salt$hash
```

Comment: Straight from Wikipedia: "the hash value is sometimes called the message digest or simply digest"

Answer (score 0):

Crypt function returns not digest itself, but concatenation of digest plus parameters (like salt, and function identifier/version/whatever else).